# Can I damage condenser mic with Phantom Power connected using unbalanced cable?

Tags: microphone, noise, power, phantom

I have Chord CM05 condenser microphone. For the first trials I bought cheap Phantom Power Supply, like this one:
[image: Phantom Power Supply I used]

Unfortunately the XLR cable I used was unbalanced one (with pins 1&3 interconnected). That means 48V occured only on pin 2, pin 3 had 0V, I figured it within one minute or so. Could it damage the mic?

Later, when I got correct balanced XLR cable and connected it, I hear only noise on the output when power is turned on and nothing when turned off.
I verified that there is approx 48V on both 2 and 3 related to pin 1.
I have unbalanced recording device behind the power supply, but it should be no issue, since power supply has blocking condensers on both signal lines (I checked it by multimeter, that DC current can't flow through.
I have no other condenser mic, but when I connect dynamic mic, sound passes through.

For now, I don't know if mic is damaged (or possibly was already defective before) or it is incompatible with this phantom power supply. Unfortunately I can't check it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The Mic can handle the phantom power, so you won't damage it by giving it phantom power. The only thing that might happen is the phantom power won't GET TO the Mic.
Pretty benign but annoying problem.